# What is wrong with my code, Please check my code?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input())
if (a==0 or a==1 or a<1):
  print("factorial is one") 
else:
  fact =1
  while(a>1):
   fact = fact *a
   a = a-1
   print("factorial:",fact)
```

and Output is Like:
6
factorial: 6
factorial: 30
factorial: 120
factorial: 360
factorial: 720

but I want only 720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation of your print statement is causing problem.

Your print statement is lying under while block scope and for your expected results it should be outside while

```
a = int(input())
if (a==0 or a==1 or a<1):
  print("factorial is one") 
else:
  fact =1
  while(a>1):
   fact = fact *a
   a = a-1
  print("factorial:",fact)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indentation problem, make print outside `while`

```
a = int(input())
if (a==0 or a==1 or a<1):
  print("factorial is one") 
else:
  fact =1
  while(a>1):
   fact = fact *a
   a = a-1
  print("factorial:",fact)
```

N.B:
the best way to do a factorial, is use a recursive function

```
def fact(n):
   return n if n ==1 else n * fact(n-1) 


number = int(input('Your nuumber'))

print('factorial', fact(number))
```